# jQuery Get Position of Character in a Div?

Tags: jquery, html, position

Hi Guys [and girls] :)

Just wondering whether it's possible to get the `absolute` positiong of a character within a div ?

```
<div class="mycooldiv">
    bunch of text is in here and for example some # and some other cool #
</div>
```

i.e. using `jQuery UI Position` perhaps or otherwise - how would I get for example the position of `#` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your element only contains text, you can wrap the character in an inline element, and get the position of the element using `.offset()`. Then, place the original text back. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dp6JR/**

```
var $elem = $('.mycooldiv');
var text = $elem.html();
var newText = text.replace(/#/, '<span class="get-position-of-it"></span>');
$elem.html(newText); //Set wrapper
var offset = $(".get-position-of-it").offset();
$elem.html(text)    ; //Place back
var topPos = offset.top;
var left = offset.left;
```

Note: This function gets the position of the first found `#` character. If you want to get the position of all characters, add `g` to the Regular expression `(/#/g`).

**Getting all positions** - **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dp6JR/1/**

The offsets of all characters will be stored in a 2-dimensional array (matrix).

```
var positions = [];
var $elem = $('.mycooldiv');
var text = $elem.html();
var newText = text.replace(/#/g, '<span class="get-position-of-it"></span>');
$elem.html(newText); //Set wrapper
$(".get-position-of-it").each(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    positions.push([offset.left, offset.top]);
});
$elem.html(text)    ; //Place back
//`positions` is an array of all offset information
```

The output can be equivalent to:

```
var positions = [
    [0, 0],
    [100, 0]
];
```

Comment: to fix use `.position()` instead.. and set container to be `position:relative`

Comment: thanks :) what about a <div contenteditable="true"> ? how would I go about targeting it in that ?

Comment: This ruins kerning and will return approximate position but not exact one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`lettering.js`](http://daverupert.com/2010/09/lettering-js/) plugin, which wraps letters (*or words or lines*) in `span` elements.

This way you can easily target them and use [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) on those elements to get their actual location in their container (*which should have `position:relative`*)..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/G7hFB/

Comment: any ideas how I do this for a symbol in a textarea ? i.e. what if like I'm wanting to find a symbol like `#` as a user is entering text into a `textarea` ?

Comment: find the location inside a `textarea` ? (*i would think it is nearly impossible to do directly, as the contents are just the `value` of the element and **not** actual content of the DOM*) You might get close if you have an invisible `div` with the same dimensions/padding/line-height/font-size etc (*whatever properties affect the size and positioning of the text inside it*).. as the `textarea` and fill it in with the contents of the `textarea`, and do the tracking inside it instead...

Comment: thanks :) what about a `<div contenteditable="true">` ? how would I go about targeting it in that ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by position? The position within the text string or the coordinates (x, y) within the bounds of its container?

If the first case you can use the `.idexOf()` method, in the second case I'd wrap that element in a `span` tag and then get its position.

Comment: yeah the second is what i'm after. i.e. the x,y position of it within the container ?