# How to get the position and size of a HTML text node using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

For Example,

```
<div style="width:100px;text-align:center">text</div>
```

I want to get the position and size of the `text` text node , not its `div` wrapper. Is it possible?

Comment: You can get the div position and then you'll have to add any top and left padding and border.

Comment: @user125697: `text` is  a node , not an element. It doesn't duplicate of that question.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913631/jquery-get-position-of-character-in-a-div) may help you

Comment: @Asken: How to get the padding and border information? I cannot find its padding and border value using the inspector of Chrome.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Finding the position/dimensions of a text node is a different problem from doing the same with an element.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In modern browsers (recent-ish Mozilla, WebKit and Opera) you can use the [`getClientRects()` method of a DOM range](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-range-interface) that encompasses the text node.

```js
var textNode = document.getElementById("wombat").firstChild;
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
var rects = range.getClientRects();
if (rects.length > 0) {
    console.log("Text node rect: ", rects[0]);
}
```

```html
<div id="wombat">Wombat</div>
```

Comment: Is this code work with old browser. if not, what solution for old browser.

Comment: @Domezchoc: Which old browsers? There is a solution using [`TextRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE which is easy so long as your text node is the only child of an element. Otherwise, it's still possible but more work to create the TextRange.

Comment: i mean IE, i got it. first i need to find TextRange and then getClientRects. thank

Comment: @user984003: The snippet seems to work OK on Safari in iOS 11.