# is there a way in JS to calculate the width of a string value and not rendered as DOM element- JS

Tags: javascript

is there a way we can get the width of a simple string- I know with the HTML markup its possible via the getting the id from the dOM and then checking the width on that element. however in my case its rendering as a string value and I need to know the width of that string in order to add ellipses based on that. I can do it via CSS, however in CSS I'll have to define the width in order to get the ellipsis. I need to have customize width based on points rendered on a chart.
is this even possible?

I tried `length`

```
var string = "Hello world- need to know width";
var len = string.length;
```

but im not sure of this is equivalent of width.

Comment: You can't tell the width until it's rendered, because it depends on the element that you're rendering it in, and its CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual width of rendered text is dependent on some factors including font-size and font-family, current zoom level and ... thus if need to apply some style like ellipsis you need to get real rendered size; I am not aware any other way than actually rendering it screen and reading the size with javascript; ( you can render it on a newly created `opacity:0` element and after calculation destroy it
or other similar ways).

by the way in this [web.dev](https://web.dev/lcp/#how-is-an-element%27s-size-determined) article they'd explained how text nodes can be considered as `lcp` in some cases which can give you insights of how text nodes rect can be calculated;
you can also check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16210994/5953610)