# How to get Character Offset from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, contentoffset

I have a div with **"contenteditable = true"**.
**For ex:**
`<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">

     <br/>fggggdf

</div>`
How to get the **character offset**(for example character `'d'` offset) with respect to the div **"editableDiv"**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want the actual offset (in pixels) of a caracter...?

Comment: @gncl <- Yes. A sort of suggestion div pops up at that place. Thanks

Comment: You want offset for some fixed characters?

Comment: @anup <- Yes. For `'#'` and `'@'` Have a look at this [screenshot](http://snag.gy/vqX1y.jpg). Thanks

Comment: Check this 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913631/jquery-get-position-of-character-in-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16575647/590525) will help you.

I was thinking of a similar approach to the one presented here. Basically, you will have to do something like this:

> It basically copies the whole text from inside the textarea into a div of the same size. I have set some CSS to ensure that in every browser, the textarea and the div wrap their content in exactly the same way.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out. You can find the offset where mouse is clicked to show your suggestion box.

http://jsfiddle.net/8dZBT/2/

```
$('#editableDiv').click(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    x -= $(this).offset().left;
    y -= $(this).offset().top;
    alert(x+' '+y)

});
```

Comment: Let me try with some modifications. Thanks